# JMETER: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, database, aws

I have configured Jmeter for database load testing, and have been using the CLI to test load on my redshift database. i have increased the memory heap but the same problem remains
[image: heap]

Below is the Error I am getting even after increasing the heap size to 5 gigabytes.

```
WARNING: package sun.awt.X11 not in java.desktop
Creating summariser <summary>
Created the tree successfully using //Users/mbyousaf/Desktop/redshit-test/test-redhsift.jmx
Starting standalone test @ Wed Dec 02 14:53:17 GMT 2020 (1606920797442)
Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
Warning: Nashorn engine is planned to be removed from a future JDK release
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid35596.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [3071802740 bytes in 3.747 secs]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your heap dump is 3 GB only and according to your configuration it should be 5 GB which makes me think that your heap size amendment hasn't been applied.

You can check what exact settings are effective for your JMeter instance by adding i.e. [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test/) to your test plan with the [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) containing the following code:

```
println('JMeter Java arguments: ')
java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each { argument -> println(argument)}
```

this way you will get something like this in the console:

[image]

If your setting is applied and you cannot allocate more heap and still cannot conduct the required load the only way I can think of is to get another machine and consider going for [Distributed Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: yes have added more heap allocation, it still somehow takes a long time to complete the queries but they are being completed now. many thanks :)